# Steam Voice Chat Problem - Sound Bar Moving, No Sound

Tags: steam, voice-chat

I have a weird problem with voice chat in Steam that nobody else seems to have. I've read a lot of posts on Steam voice chat problems that start to sound like this one but end up being something else by the time I finish reading. So the problem is I'm not getting sound to come through in voice chat but I'm sure that Steam is receiving the sound because the bar is moving next the speaker icon but I just can't figure out where the sound is being sent to because I can't hear it in my speakers or headphones. All my friends can hear me too. The problem is on my end on my computer for sure, we've pinned it down. (I should also note I'm using a USB mic and normal headphones together, not a headset. This COULD be the problem but I can't figure out why it would be an issue.) I'm trying to look for settings in Steam on where to send the sound but it looks like there are just mic settings, nothing to help fix this problem.

Comment: Click Start Menu > Control Panel > System > Device Manager and check that under sound you don't have any missing drivers. Furthermore check if you've got all the bus drivers downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said nothing about it, first check Audio devices.
Right click you Volume icon (looks like Dynamic) in system tray -> Playback Devices
Here you will see what device is currently used by default. Steam obeys these settings.

If you have more than one active device, Headphones should be "Set as Default Communication Device".

Then right click on Headphones and "Test".